# Inline keyboard Telegram bot [PHP]

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I want that my bot when I write /orario he answer me with a inline keyboard.

So.. I created an array for my keyboard in this way:

```
$tastierino_giorno = '[{"text":"Testo","callback_data":"StampaMessaggio"}]';
```

and in another function I write this:

```
function tastieraInline($chatid, $tastierino)
{
    global $token;
    $messaggio = "Scegli per che giorno inviare il messaggio:";
    $tastiera = '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": 
  ['.urlencode($tastierino).'],"resize_keyboard":true}';
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$chatId&parse_mode=HTML&text=".urlencode($messaggio).$tastiera;

    file_get_contents($url);

}
```

After this, with an if, I check if the users has write "/orario".

```
} elseif($message == "/orario"){
        tastieraInline($chatid, $tastierino_giorno); 
}
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't works... what's the problem?

Comment: we need a [mcve] but I can't see any reason why `$message` would ever be anything other than `"Scegli per che giorno inviare il messaggio:"`

Comment: Yes you are right. But how can i post a full example? Can i use an extern site?

Comment: This is the full code of my bot: https://pastebin.com/Y0mGx8iw

Comment: What do you mean of it doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$tastiera = '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": 
  ['.urlencode($tastierino).'],"resize_keyboard":true}';
```

to

```
$tastiera = '&reply_markup='.urlencode('{"inline_keyboard": 
  ['.$tastierino.'],"resize_keyboard":true}');
```

you should URL encode the whole JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the result returned from your telegram calls. `file_get_contents` is great for getting something working quickly but doesn't return any error information.

You should use curl or a library like [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/). An example for curl:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
if ( $ch == FALSE )
{
  error_log( "Error initialising curl" );
  return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1 );
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Connection: Close' ) );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
$error = curl_errno( $ch );
$errorStr = curl_error( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
if ( $error != 0 )
{
  return array( $errorStr, $result );
}
return $result;
```

Guzzle is a lot simpler if you don't mind installing an additional library.

Hopefully this will get you the error string from your failed telegram calls.

Onto your actual issue. You should create json for the keyboard markup using `json_encode` rather than appending strings. [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) makes building URLs much easier.